# Extra space after cross reference

Tags: spacing, formatting, cross-referencing

When I make a cross reference with \ref inside the paragraph, resultant chapter includes extra vertical space after the reference line.

[image: reference inside paragraph]

When I make a \ref at the end of the paragraph, space between that paragraph and next paragraph becomes more than normal. So adding a cross reference adds extra vertical space in any case.

[image: reference at the end of paragraph]

When I add multiple cross references in a paragraph, this makes this vertical space bigger. For example 4 reference makes that space 4 times bigger.

[image: multiple referemces]

What would be the cause for this extra vertical space ?

You can find my example from following link https://www.overleaf.com/read/mvfqcpjxbcwx

Comment: You should show (small)  examples on this site and not link to files which will be gone in a few days.

Comment: this question is archived forever and would not make sense if the example at the link changes

Comment: I added overleaf link as read only, so it won't change. Minimal example includes def and cls files which are not possible to copy paste here. If you say that, copy-paste only necessary parts of def file, I don't know which part makes problem.

Comment: I added screenshots, maybe it can help.

Comment: better would have been to add the example code so people can run it.

Comment: but this time I've followed the link and am looking at the code:-)

Comment: Wow! `\def\thechapter{\vspace*{10pt} \arabic{chapter}}` is one of the craziest things I've seen!

Comment: @egreg I was just writing an answer that said more or less the same:-)

Comment: @Mark do you _have_ to use this class file, it is not one I would choose.

Comment: My university gave me this for latex template. If I don't use MS Word, unfortunately I should use this template. I asked them that there are errors, they replied me that they will fix it. But I suppose it will be slow.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369125/35864

Comment: oh @egreg and i have both seen that before:(

Comment: I couldn't find it, thank you moewe. Thank you David and egreg for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the class file has

```
\def\thechapter{\vspace*{10pt} \arabic{chapter}
```

which makes no sense and forced 10pt space on the line after any line that references a chapter number (including tables as they use the form chapter.table.

Just delete the `\vspace*{10pt}`

Comment: Instead of changing the class file, one can just add `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}` in the preamble.

Comment: @egreg true but the class file is just so blatently unusable, changing it rather than patching it in the document may help the next year's batch of students